# Azure: Compare dates in Data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Data factory doesn't have a built-in date difference function. I want to compare lastModified date and utcnow in if condition activity. How can I achieve it?

```
@greaterOrEquals(activity('Get Metadata1').output.lastModified, '2015-03-15T13:27:36Z')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by converting year and month part of dates to integers and comparing them.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `ticks` function to convert it to integer.
[Logic Apps function reference for Ticks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#ticks)

The ADF UI may show a warning about it not being a recognized function, but ADF is actually using logic app expressions so it will succeed if you debug or trigger the pipeline.

Comment: The ticks function that you linked is for Azure Logic Apps, not Azure Data Factory. I just tried it and ticks is not a recognized function in Data Factory.

Comment: Actually they are the same. ADF is using logic app expression. Though UI may show warning, runtime will success if you debug or trigger your pipeline.

Answer (score 2):

we can get date difference count between 2 dates.
**@string(div(div(div(div(sub(ticks(variables('presentdate')),ticks(variables('pastdate'))),10000000),60),60),24))**

Comment: The MS Dev team for ADF pipelines should be ashamed of themselves for this.

Comment: Must be architected by an intern - passionate to write [dis]assembly like coding for senior developers who have never seen such style of functions or calculations. 

Crazy! how many syntax one should learn!! So Inconsistency.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem today where I needed a check to see whether the `utcNow()` time was greater than 2AM (inside an if block in the Data Factory).

On the above advice, I used the `ticks()` function. I'm sure its not the most elegant but wasn't sure how to convert the hour section of the datetimes nicely as it seemed that `hour()` wasnt supported.

`@if(greaterOrEquals(div(sub(ticks(utcNow()),ticks(startOfDay(utcNow()))),36000000000),2))True,False)`

with the 36,000,000,000 division converting the 100ns ticks into the number of hours between the `utcNow()` and the `startOfday(utcNow())`